# Change button background color on click event?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-button

When I declare a button on an activity and set the `android:onClick` attribute, the activity automatically changes the background color of the button when pressed.

Now I've got a button on a fragment. Since I can't use `android:onClick` here, I'm doing it with a `onClickListener` instead. The button works, however it doesn't change it's style anymore.

Do I have to do this manually? How?

Comment: You can use a `Background Selector` as a background of your button, to handle `pressed`, `focused`... states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need an XML file, `drawable` selector. I named this file with `res/drawable/bg_button.xml`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_button_pressed"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_button_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_button_normal" />  <!-- normal state -->
</selector>
```

For `res/drawable/bg_button_pressed.xml`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="color when pressed" />
</shape>
```

Create a new XML file, name it `res/drawable/bg_button_normal.xml`, and copy above code. Then, replace `android:color` with normal color, i.e. when button on normal state.

And finally:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/..."
    android:text="@string/..."
    android:background="@drawable/bg_button"/>
```

If you didn't have `res/drawable` folder, create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

1. Reference your button

   ```
   yourButton = (Button) <fragment name>.findViewById(R.id.<button id>);
   yourButton.setOnClickListener(this);
   ```
2. And within your click event ,

   ```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   switch (v.getId()) {

   case R.id.yourButton:
       yourButton.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(<colour code>));
       break;

   default:
       break;
   }
   }
   ```